# How to pass float value where datatype is CMTime?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, mixing

I am creating an application in which I have to mix the songs. I have accomplished this but the problem is when I am using the following function.

```
- (BOOL)insertTimeRange:(CMTimeRange)timeRange ofTrack:(AVAssetTrack *)track atTime:(CMTime)startTime error:(NSError **)error;
```

I have to pass **CMTime** type value in the **atTime** parameter but it doesn't takes Float value and I have to add the another song at some floating point value. Is it possible any how?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use one of the `CMTimeMake...()` [functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009748-CH201-SW10). You have to supply a time point and a timescale value. The former is a 64-bit integer; you can just truncate or round your `float` to convert it to an integer, or use a necessarily high timescale:

```
CMTime tm = CMTimeMake(53425, 10000); // @ 5.3425 sec
```

Comment: I don't need Integer value. Here is an example, Suppose there is a song with duration 10 secs and I have to mix one more song at 5.3425 secs. But since "atTime" parameter takes only CMTime Value and it is Integer and when I am using the CMTimeMake(5.3425, 1.0); it is returning me 5.00000 and the song gets added at 5.00000 not at 5.3425.

Comment: @Harsh Why can't you just set the timescale to something reasonable then? For example, 5.3425 can be represented as `CMTimeMake(53425, 10000)`...

Comment: It worked! :-) Accepted you answer! Thanks but why it was not working with CMTimeMake(5.3425, 1.0);?

Comment: @Harsh Only if you read the documentation... the first argument of the function is the numerator and the second is the denominator of a fraction. And it accepts integers, so no matter you have a float, C's type system will truncate it.

Comment: @Harsh `CMTimeMake(5.3425, 1.0)` fails because the `timescale` value means `CMTimeMake` will not return anything smaller than 1 second. `The precision of the CMTime object as a whole is limited by this quantity. For example, if timescale is 1, no timestamp smaller than 1 second can be represented by the object, and timestamps go in increments of one second. Similarly, if timescale is 1000, each second is subdivided into 1000 pieces, and the value member represents the number of milliseconds we want to signify.` Details here: https://warrenmoore.net/understanding-cmtime

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1

```
CMTimeMake(value: 53425, timescale: 10000)// @ 5.3425 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift version

```swift
CMTime(seconds: 5.3425, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(1000))
```

Set `preferredTimescale` larger to get more precision.

---

Availability

iOS 7.0+ macOS 10.9+ Mac Catalyst 13.0+ tvOS 9.0+ watchOS 6.0+ Xcode 7.1+

Also check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/cmtime/1489786-init).

Answer (score 0):

sadly every answer uses hard coded `CMTimeScale(1000)`, the right way is

```
let t = CMTimeMake(value: 53425, timescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))
```